# Android Google Analytics screen metrics don't show up in console

Tags: android, google-analytics

I created an analytics profile for my android app yesterday and added screen views for my activities.  I see the messages are being sent to analytics in the logs and there are no errors but I am yet to see any traffic show up in the analytics console.

Is there a normal delay after account creation before analytics data show up in the console or is there something I am missing?

I am using latest revision of Analytics SDK V4 and running on Galaxy S4 4.4.4 Kitkat

Here is what I am seeing in logcat:

12-03 12:21:53.181: V/GAV4(11601): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
12-03 12:21:53.221: V/GAV4(11601): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
12-03 12:21:53.221: V/GAV4(11601): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: ul=en-us,  ht=xxxxxxx,  sr=1080x1920,  a=xxxxxxxx,  sc=start,  sf=100.0,  aid=com.company.package,  cid=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx,  av=0.1.4,  v=1,  t=screenview,  an=xxxx Android,  tid=UAxxxxxxxx,  _u=.r3998,  cd=User Reviews,

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch
You can try decrease dispatch time with:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(<time in seconds>);
```